# Integrability of a function

Tags: real-analysis

we know that  $f(x)=e^x$ is not in $L^2(R^n)$.Iwant to prove this by using the fact that  the limit of $P(x)=x $ doesn't exist as $|x|$ goes to $+\infty$ .Can someone help me please .Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know what does $L^2$ mean?

Comment: yes f is in $L^2 $ if and only if $ \int_{R^n} |f(x)|^2 dx$ is finite

Comment: You say your on $\mathbb{R}^n$? The function you have written is a function of a single variable.

Comment: In fact i want to prove in a general case  that if $P(x)$ is a polynomial which doesn't have a limit as |x| goes to +∞ then $f(x)=e^{-P(x)}$  is not in $L^2(R^n)$

Comment: so how could a function which tends to infinity be in $L^2$?

Comment: if P(x) doesn't have  a limit as |x| goes to +∞ this implies that f(x)=e^{−P(x)} goes to $+\infty$ as  |x| goes to +∞?

Comment: why don't you try to show that given an arbitrary constant $M$, $e^{P(x)}$ is bounded below by $M$ for large $x$.

Comment: You may need to rewrite your question. What do you want to prove?

Comment: hence as i understood we write :if P(x) doesn't have a limit as |x| goes to +∞ this implies that $f(x)=e^{−P(x)}$ goes to +∞ as |x| goes to +∞.Hence there exits a positive constant M such that $e^{−P(x)}\ge M$ for |x| large .Or M $\notin L^2$ hence $f(x)=e^{−P(x)}\notin L^2$

Comment: what i wrote is it right to answer  the original question?:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742599/function-which-is-not-in-l2rn?noredirect=1#comment3556811_1742599