# Change of variables of a polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, spectral-theory

Can someone help me please  to solve this problem:
we consider $V(Y)$ a polynomial in $ R[Y_1,Y_2,..,Y_d] $
I want to prove that there existe an affine change of variables $ Y=AX+B,X=(X_1,X_2,..,X_d)$ and there exist $n=n(V)\in N $ such that : 
1) for any  $j∈${$1,..,n(V)$}  we have $∂_{X_j}V=$ complex constant
2)for any $j∈${$n(V)+1,..,d$} there exist $f_j∈R[X_{j+1},..,X_d]$ such that  $X_j+f_j(X_{j+1},..,X_d)∈ Span ${$∂_XV,α∈N^d,|α|≥1$} 
indication: 
consider the linear map  $∂_{Y_j},j=1,..,d$ which send the finite vector space  $F_p=Span${$∂_XV,α∈N^d,|α|≥p$} to $F_{p+1}$ and construct the  coordonnates  $X_j $by reverse induction  in a  Jordan approch.

Comment: What is $r$? Why is it there?

Comment: $E_r$ denotes the set of all polynomial  in $R[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$ of degree less or equal to $r$ (we fix $r$ in the begening of the problem)

Comment: But why restrict the degree? Why not just say if v is a polynomial and e^-v is in L^2, then v has a local max?

Comment: yes you are there is no need to restrict the degree.