# Function in $ L^2(R^n)$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that

if $V$ is a polynomial in  $R[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$ such  $e^{−V(X)}∈L^2(R^n)$

then $e^{−V(X)}$ has a local maximum.

This is what i tried to do:

I wrote $V(X)=|X|^{a_1}f_1\Big(\dfrac X{|X|}\Big) +|X|^{a_2}f_2\Big(\dfrac X{|X|}\Big)+\ldots+|X|^{a_m}f_m\Big(\dfrac X{|X|}\Big)$
with $f_i \in C^\infty, \forall i\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$

and $a_1\ge a_2\ge\cdots\ge a_m\ge 0$

if we had $V(X)=|X|^{a}f\Big(\dfrac X{|X|}\Big)$

then $\displaystyle \int _{\mathbb R^n} e^{-V(X)}dx=\int_0^{+\infty} \int _{S^{n-1}}e^{-r^{a}f(b)}r^{n-1}dr db=\frac 1{a}\Big(\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{t^n}{a-1} e^{-t} dt \Big)\int _{S^{n-1}} f(b)^{-n/a}db$

Can someone help me please.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a multivariable polynomial? Is $x+y$ a polynomial in this sense? What about $xy$?

Comment: the two examples which you gave represent multivariable polynomials

Comment: Can you provide a link to the definition?Is this what you mean: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultivariatePolynomial.html

Comment: yes this is what i mean but instead of using (x,y) we have n variables $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ in what i wrote before X=$(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$

Answer (score 0):

Assume that
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left( e^{-V(x)} \right)^2 \, \mathrm{d}x < \infty. $$

Let $x^* \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Since $$
e^x > 0,
$$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have that $c = \left( e^{-V(x^*)} \right)^2 > 0.$ Since $\left( e^{-V(x)} \right)^2$ is integrable and $V$ is a polynomial, the function has to vanish at inifnity: there is a compact set $K$ such that $\left( e^{-V(x)} \right)^2 < \dfrac{c}{2}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus K$. On the other hand, $\left( e^{-V(K)} \right)^2$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$, since $\left( e^{-V(x)} \right)^2$ is a composition of continuous functions. Thus $\left( e^{-V(x)} \right)^2$ attains it's maximum value in $K$, which is its maximum value in $\mathbb{R}^n$, since $\left( e^{-V(x)} \right)^2 < \dfrac{c}{2}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus K$.

Assume that the maximizer is not unique in a small neighborhood. Then, since it is a polynomial, $V$ would be constant along a line and $\left( e^{-V(x)} \right)^2$  would not vanish at infinity. Contradiction. Thus there is a unique maximum.

Comment: This is a bit awkward and some details are left out, but it should work.

Comment: I didn't understand why we have "Since $(e^{−V(x)})^2$ is integrable and Vis a polynomial, the function has to vanish at inifnity"

Comment: The restriction of $V$ on a line can be considered as a polynomial of a single variable. This either tends to infinity of negative infinity. In order for the integral of the composition $\left( e^{-V(x)} \right)^2$ to converge, it has to tend to infinity.

Comment: If the function didn't vanish, it's value would be greater than $\varepsilon > 0$ in a set of an infinite measure, and the integral would not converge.

Comment: I don't show it rigorously here, but you should be able to do that quite easily.

Comment: we couldn't have :$e^{−V(x)} $ doesnt have a limit as |x| tend to $+\infty$?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure that's impossible. It has to tend to zero, because a polynomial cannot oscillate an infinite number of times.

Comment: If it didn't tend to zero to some direction, it would tend to infinity in that direction.

Comment: i didn't understand how to prove that :"If the function didn't vanish, it's value would be greater than ε>0 in a set of an infinite measure, and the integral would not converge" why in a set of infinite measure?

Comment: you can find here an example where V doesn't tend to $+\infty$ (hence $e^{-V(X)}$ doesn't tend to 0) and $e^{-V(X)}\notin L^2$ given by ZHW:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742599/function-which-is-not-in-l2rn/1745674#1745674

Comment: Yes, but that's what I'm claiming. I think it cannot be the other way around: $e^{-V(x)}$ not tending to zero and $e^{-V(x)} \in L^2$

Comment: sorry in the example we have $e^{−V(x)}$ not tending to zero and  $e^{−V(x)}∈L^2$